# how to write formula in sf to show percentage

Tags: formula, reporting, formula-field, charts

I have a chart showing following information but now i need to have instead of numbers the percentage.
Now it shows percentage of all records. But im interested if its possible to count % separately for A, and separately for B and D.
How should i write formula? I'm vey new with SF

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SSE ! Do you want the % of count ?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala yes, exactly

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala your advice is very good. I have updated my question, can you have a look if the formula can be improved to show % for A, B and D
I mean if we look at A, then it has 133 records and its around 60%

Comment: Do you want percentage calculation different. Are these on same report? or have to added them as matrix of reports?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala yes, i want % be calculated differently. I wandering if its possible to calculate 100% of records for A (B and D) separately.
Like total record for A is 190 Then
-133 is around 70%
A 12 is around 5%
B 23 is around 12%
C 5 is around 3%
D 19 is around

Comment: Yes Got it. Is it single report or you concatenated  different reports?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala its a single report

Answer (score 2):

You can create a formula field  in the report to show the percentage. The formula should be as below.

```
 (RowCount / PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, GRAND_SUMMARY)) *100
```

[image]

Please find the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386586&type=1) for the same

Answer (score 0):

solution:
RowCount / PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, here i wrote the field name)